# How to use Lodash get function to get the nested array objects

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I need to get the array of object values without using foreach by using lodash get function

```
"PaymentTypes": [
    {
      "categoryName": "Payment Type 1",
      "paymentOptions": [{"payCode": "PType1"}]
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "Payment Type 2",
      "paymentOptions": [{"payCode": "PType2"},{"payCode": "PType3"}]
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "Payment Type 3",
      "paymentOptions": [{"payCode": "PType4"}]
    }
]
```

I want to have all the paycode in single variable like :

```
const payCode ={"PType1","PType2","PType3","PType4"};
```

I have used lodash get function to get values using category name but not sure how to get the paycode type for each category in a single object using lodash get function

```
const category = get(PaymentTypes,"PaymentOptions");
```

Comment: The question is a little hard to read due to sloppy formatting btw. For example `{"PType1","PType2","PType3","PType4"}` is not the way in js to format an array. And your js object has no beginning, it just starts with `"PaymentTypes": [{`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a combination of [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

We'd call .flatMap() on the `PaymentTypes` array, then call .map() on the paymentOptions array to get all payCodes:

```js
const obj = { "PaymentTypes": [{ "categoryName": "Payment Type 1", "paymentOptions": [{ "payCode": "PType1"}] }, { "categoryName": "Payment Type 2", "paymentOptions": [{ "payCode": "PType2"}, {"payCode": "PType3"}] }, { "categoryName": "Payment Type 3", "paymentOptions": [{ "payCode": "PType4"}] } ] }

const result = obj.PaymentTypes.flatMap(({ paymentOptions }) => { 
    return paymentOptions.map(({ payCode }) => payCode)
});

console.log('Result:', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Array.map function instead.

```
const payCodes = paymentTypes.map(o => o.payCode);
```